# Gaining rep from "survey" questions

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm a little embarrassed. My [highest-rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756127/building-pdf-files-with-c/756131#756131), by a large margin, is on a question that's really just a survey question. The OP wanted to know about experiences with different PDF generation tools, and I was the first to answer how much I like iTextSharp. Basically all I said was "I like iTextSharp;" not exactly Jon Skeet material. Yet the answer was accepted and I keep getting upvotes for it.

I feel guilty, like I shouldn't be getting credit for just saying I like a certain piece of software. Is there anything I can do to cut off the stream of unjustified rep from this question?

Comment: I know what you mean; I once got 17 upvotes for saying that I'd heard good things about Hudson (a Java continuous integration server), and I don't even use it myself.

Comment: I also heard good things about hudson (upvote me)

Comment: To remember for a next code review: "not exactly Jon Skeet material". Much better than "what is your own opinion on this?" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag them and we'll convert them to community wiki mode. If it's a "List of X" question, without a definite and concrete answer, that's what we usually do.

Comment: Thanks for the information, and for (apparently) taking care of that for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can make your answer community wiki if you like, and that will prevent any further rep.

However, 16 upvotes for a soft answer isn't all that bad in the grand scheme of things. Some of us have committed far worse sins.

Comment: It's also completely reasonable for an answer that's nearly a year old - sometimes this happens in a matter of minutes!  Someone recently got 25 upvotes in that much time for a 4-word answer to "how do you pronounce XAML".

Comment: This is my favourite example of easy rep harvesting (and it got a Reversal badge too) -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604124/what-does-the-in-a-za-z0-9-mean/1604128#1604128

Comment: far, far worse.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely nothing to worry about IMO. Simple answers get mass-upvoted every day. Sometimes even incorrect or stupid ones!

As you will see over time, providing deep, fundamental and well-researched answers often doesn't yield any reputation at all, or very, very little. I'm not meaning that in any bitter way - it's just how things work, and very much down to how people tick when voting, myself included. And sometimes the opposite will happen, a simple, effortless answer you didn't think twice about will get upvoted seemingly beyond reason.

Plus, I don't see anything wrong with the process here: 16 people repeated your statement that they are very happy with the software in question. While that may not be good enough for a review article in a computer magazine, it pretty much brings across the point.