# Robotics off-topic at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions, scope

My question, 
 *[What are good communities for robotics and electronics ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753068/what-are-good-communities-for-robotics-and-electronics-closed)*, was [closed]

It's interesting robotics is off-topic for programming. Moderators should have to explain a little, at least for gray areas.

Comment: That's not robotics

Comment: Belongs on roboOverflow.com o.O

Answer (score 7):

First, you are asking for a list of X. Thus it should have been marked as Community Wiki. See for example [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44021/gaining-rep-from-survey-questions/44050#44050) to [Gaining rep from “survey” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44021). Or see: [What about a multi-answer question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9782)

Second, there is nothing in the question to indicate it is about software development. If it had been more specific then it could have survived.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't have said that robotics programming is off topic as you can see from the number of questions tagged `robotics` that remain open. However robotics and electronics in general is off topic as it isn't related totally to programming.

Your question also wasn't closed by a moderator but by normal users. I think the explanation given was good enough:

> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally **relate to programming or software development** in some way, within the scope defined in the faq.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of overlap in robotics, electronics, and programming, but they're not the same thing (I've worked in all three areas).  If your question is about programming robots I'm sure it will remain open.  If it's about embedded programming of electronics it will probably stay open too.  That specific question seems to fall in the area of robotics and electronics that *isn't* programming related, though, so I think it was right to direct you elsewhere.  [Chiphacker](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is the perfect place for your question.